# How to apply group by function of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In pandas, I'm trying to apply a nonlinear function f(x,y) that take two vectors and returns an equal length vector z. I want to apply this function *by group* to a pandas dataframe.

Here is an MRE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
groups = ['Alice']*2 + ['Ben']*4 + ['Charlie']*3
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':groups,'col1':np.arange(len(groups)),'col2':3*col1})


def f(x,y):
    return np.max(x) + np.max(y) + np.array(x)
```

I would like a third column, call it 'col3' equal to f(x,y). The function f here is only for illustration (obviously I could do this step-wise by calculating max, but my actual f is much more complicated); the problem should work for any function f that takes an n-vector x, an n-vector y, and returns an n-vector z.

I tried

`df['col3']= df.groupby('name',as_index = False)[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x: f(x.col1,x.col2))` 
I expected to get a dataframe where col3 is 4, 5, 22, 23, 24, 25, 38, 39, 40.

Instead, it seemed to populate the entire vector for that group sequentially:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make these slight changes to make it work:

```py
def f(x, y):
    return np.max(x) + np.max(y) + x  # <-- remove np.array(x)


# use group_keys=False
df["col3"] = df.groupby("name", group_keys=False)[["col1", "col2"]].apply(
    lambda g: f(g["col1"], g["col2"])
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      name  col1  col2  col3
0    Alice     0     0     4
1    Alice     1     3     5
2      Ben     2     6    22
3      Ben     3     9    23
4      Ben     4    12    24
5      Ben     5    15    25
6  Charlie     6    18    38
7  Charlie     7    21    39
8  Charlie     8    24    40
```

---

EDIT: If the `f()` return `numpy.array`, you can construct `pd.Series` with correct index:

```py
def f(x, y):
    return np.max(x) + np.max(y) + np.array(x)


# use group_keys=False
df["col3"] = df.groupby("name", group_keys=False)[["col1", "col2"]].apply(
    lambda g: pd.Series(f(g["col1"], g["col2"]), index=g.index)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      name  col1  col2  col3
0    Alice     0     0     4
1    Alice     1     3     5
2      Ben     2     6    22
3      Ben     3     9    23
4      Ben     4    12    24
5      Ben     5    15    25
6  Charlie     6    18    38
7  Charlie     7    21    39
8  Charlie     8    24    40
```

Comment: If the output of f() is an np.array, is there anything i can do (i.e. change the type of the output) to make it work?

Comment: @cybervision I've updated my answer.